# Obtener InputStream en una clase que ha sido ejecutada por otra a la cual se ha enviado un Stream

Tags: java, input

Estoy haciendo una clase que ejecuta a otra clase mediante un Process (me han pedido que lo haga así).
La clase que quiero ejecutar tiene un metodo que determina si una cadena es palíndroma.

```
private void esCadenaPalindroma() {
    final String CADENATRATADA = cadena.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");

    cadenaPalindroma = true;

    int indice = 0;
    int indiceInverso = CADENATRATADA.length() - 1;

    do {
        if (CADENATRATADA.charAt(indice) == CADENATRATADA.charAt(indiceInverso)) {
            indice++;
            indiceInverso--;
        } else {
            cadenaPalindroma = false;
        }
    } while ((cadenaPalindroma) && (indice <= (CADENATRATADA.length() - 1) / 2));
}
```

Y esta clase debe de ser ejecutada por el método main de otra clase mediante un subproceso, lo cuál he hecho de esta forma

```
public class EjecutarPrograma {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int valorSalida = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean salir = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Este programa comprueba si la cadena que el usuario introduzca es palíndroma o no, "
                + "\ntambién comprueba si está vacía."
                + "\nPuede introducir la cadena mediante el teclado o mediante un archivo."
                + "\nEl resultado será mostrado en pantalla"
                + "\n¿Va a introducir la cadena mediante el teclado o mediante un archivo?"
                + "\nIntroduzca 1 si lo hará mediante el teclado."
                + "\nIntroduzca 2 si lo hará mediante un archivo."
                + "\nIntroduzca cualquier otro número si desea abandonar el programa");
        int opcion = sc.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Introduce la cadena que deseas comprobar: ");
            String cadena = sc.nextLine();
            File directorio = new File(".\\bin");
            File ficheroErrores = new File("errores.log");
            File ficheroSalida = new File("salida.txt");
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "main.java.ComprobarCadenaPalindroma");
            builder.directory(directorio);
            builder.redirectError(ficheroErrores);
            builder.redirectOutput(ficheroSalida);
            try {
                Process p = builder.start();
                OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
                os.write(cadena.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                valorSalida = p.waitFor();
                
                System.out.println("Valor de salida: " + valorSalida);
                
                
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        case 2:
        default:
            salir = true;
            break;
        }

    } while (!salir);

}
```

Como se puede ver en el código, mediante el método getOutputStream() quiero obtener el Stream de datos que entra en el subproceso para poder escribir en el Stream de datos la cadena que quiero evaluar en la clase java ComprobarCadenaPallindroma.class, en la que está el método que comprueba si la cadena es Palíndroma o si está vacía.
La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener ese InputStream dentro del método main de la clase que va a llamar al método esCadenaPalindroma?
Si fuera en una misma clase usaría la propia instancia de Process llamando al método getInputStream, pero en este caso, no sé cómo hacerlo.
Así es como tengo mi método main de la clase ComprobarCadenaPalindroma cuando quise probarlo sin el subproceso.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de caracteres para comprobar si es un palíndromo"
            + ", si has introducido una cadena no palíndroma y no vacía o si la cadena está vacía: ");

    ComprobarCadenaPalindroma comprueba = new ComprobarCadenaPalindroma(entrada.nextLine());
    
    comprueba.esCadenaPalindroma();
    comprueba.esCadenaVacia();
    System.out.println(comprueba.toString());
    
    
    entrada.close();
}
```